# have a error like "malformedXML: During update: j_idt8:showTime not found"

Tags: ajax, jsf

i am using the jsf 2.0 and with the ajax and when i select the item from the dropdown box i want it to show me the item from the showTime list

xhtml file:

```
                <tr>
                <td>Movies:</td>
                <td>
                    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{locationBean.movie}"
                                     disabled="#{locationBean.movieListDisabled}"
                                     id="movieList">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{locationBean.movies}"/>
                        <f:ajax render="showTime"/>
                    </h:selectOneMenu></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Availablity:</td>
                <td>
                    <ui:repeat value="#{locationBean.showTime}" var="item" id="showTime">
                        <div><h:inputText value="#{item.value}" id="showTime"/></div>
                    </ui:repeat>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

and from bean i am returning the list of the showTiming ..

how to get over this error

Answer (score 1):

From BalusC: "the  by itself doesn't generate any HTML, therefore JS/Ajax can't find anything in HTML to update/render"

Try something like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>Movies:</td>
    <td>
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{locationBean.movie}" disabled="#{locationBean.movieListDisabled}" id="movieList">
            <f:selectItems value="#{locationBean.movies}"/>
            <f:ajax event="change" render="showTimePanel"/>
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Availablity:</td>
    <td>
        <h:panelGroup id="showTimePanel">
            <ui:repeat value="#{locationBean.showTime}" var="item">
                <div><h:inputText value="#{item.value}"></div>
            </ui:repeat>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: All your points are utterly wrong. The solution in code, however, is correct (although the `event` attribute is entirely superfluous and the component IDs didn't need to be removed). In other words, you have no idea how this problem is caused.

Comment: Hi @BalusC, thank you for the feedback. I'm not an expert in JSF I'm just trying to help Jay how I can. If you could provide the _right_ explanation that would be great, I would like to know.

Comment: Simple: the `<ui:repeat>` by itself doesn't generate any HTML, therefore JS/Ajax can't find anything in HTML to update/render.